# How to download all videos with yt-dlp from a youtube channel after the redesign?

Tags: command-line, youtube, yt-dlp

Youtube has recently had a redesign of its UI and apparently it's APIs where video content are now divided by regular videos, live streamed videos, and shorts among others. And to download all videos from a channel prior to the change, I would use the url: `youtube.com/c/{channelName}/videos` or `youtube.com/channel/{channelId}/videos` (whichever was available). This caused an issue with yt-dlp to not be able to find videos for certain channels, especially if it didn't have regular videos. [2022.11.11](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/releases/tag/2022.11.11) supposedly [fixed the tab handling](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/pull/5439) but it isn't quite right. With my old scripts, the above doesn't find all videos it seems.

How do I specify I want to download all videos? Will I have to run the command for each tab individually now or is there a way to make it work again for *all* videos?

e.g.,

```
yt-dlp -f ... -o ... --download-archive ... --match-filter ... https://www.youtube.com/c/somechannel/videos
```

I've been using the workaround using the "UU" channel playlist but apparently that isn't perfect and has issues. Do I need to change the url to `youtube.com/c/{channelName}` to get all videos? Plus it isn't trivial getting the channelid for any channel or the channel playlist quickly so I'd want to avoid it if I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like now, the intended way to download all the content from a channel is to use the full channel url with no specific tab.

So you'd download with the urls:

[https://www.youtube.com/c/{channelName}](https://www.youtube.com/c/%7BchannelName%7D)
[https://www.youtube.com/channel/{channelId}](https://www.youtube.com/channel/%7BchannelId%7D)
[https://www.youtube.com/@{userName}](https://www.youtube.com/@%7BuserName%7D)

What will happen is yt-dlp will treat this specially and download the `videos`, `live` and `shorts` tabs separately. If you wanted go back to the previous behavior and download the channel's featured videos, you'd have to download the `featured` tab directly.

When I was testing earlier, this was previously not working for me but I didn't know why. It turned out that with the new behavior and with me having filters set, the playlists were failing the filters which caused nothing to happen. Though [it will be fixed](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/issues/5509) in the next release.